# Tikz scientific notation vs. decimal number on x and y axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I found an interesting potential glitch in `tikzpicture` in that the arbitrary placement of `scaled ticks = false, tick label style ={/pgf/number format/fixed}` within the `\begin{axis}[]` makes a real difference of whether you see scientific notation or decimal notation on the axes.  Can anyone explain?

Code below (the only difference is the relative placement of the above) and respective output:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
title={my title},
xlabel={$x$},
ylabel={$f(x)$}],
scaled ticks = false,
tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed}
]

\addplot[black, thick, mark=o, only marks]
    coordinates {
(0.134,0.0989)
(0.102,0.0834)
(0.087,0.06)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
scaled ticks = false,
tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
title={my title},
xlabel={$x$},
ylabel={$f(x)$}]
]

\addplot[black, thick, mark=o, only marks]
    coordinates {
(0.134,0.0989)
(0.102,0.0834)
(0.087,0.06)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Add `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}` and get surprised!

Comment: @HarishKumar The newest version is `1.12` if you can upgrade :-)

Comment: @darthbith not yet on miktex, I think. :(

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because updating the package with the proper `compat` key value the problem is not reproducible.